# How to send server data to oracle db?

Tags: html, node.js, oracle

I created a html form,fetched data from user and sent to node js server.How to insert that data into oracle db?I am able to come across a lot of syntax examples for mongo amd mysql but unable to get one for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [node-oracledb module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb).  There is [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html) and [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) available.